# Should I renew my passport before the US visa interview?

Tags: passport-renewals, us-visa

My passport will expire by mid February 2019. I will be visiting India this November and will have a visa interview for H-1 stamping. Is it okay to take a passport that will be expiring in 3 months to the interview? I can renew my passport after the interview.

Comment: For some tourist visas, they ask that you bring a passport valid for your proposed stay and a few months over. Unsure if they actually enforce it, and if it's the same for H-1, but just a heads up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renew your passport before the interview, unless your country has specific agreement with the USA.

[Required Documentation](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) per Department of State website.

> Gather and prepare the following required documents before your visa
>   interview:
>
> Passport valid for travel to the United States – Your passport must be
>   valid for at least six months beyond your period of stay in the United
>   States (unless exempt by country-specific agreements).